# VBS multiple REPLACE usage

Tags: vbscript, rsync, text-editor, overwrite, file-writing

I did logEditor for my RSYNC log his task is to replace status strings in generated log file and created edited new one for end user. For this I am using REPLACE method im VBS. Everything is working well exept one problem, which I still cant solve.

When I use REPLACE multiple times then it takes only first replace usage, writes it into file and ignore others. But i need to use replace multipletimes to replace multiple statuses

```
Function logEditor(strInputFile, strLogFileName)
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

'replaceOfStatus
strNewText1 = Replace(strText, "cd+++++++++", "CDir")
'this one is going to be ignored
strNewText2 = Replace(strText, "<f+++++++++", "FILE")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLogFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText1 'writed one
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 'ignored one
objFile.Close
End Function
call logEditor(strInputFile, strLogFileName)
```

This is sample of rsync log

```
2018/04/27 12:29:40 [792] .d..t...... texlive/
2018/04/27 12:33:31 [792] cd+++++++++ texlive/Downloads/
2018/04/27 12:33:31 [792] <f+++++++++ texlive/Downloads/Backup.zip
2018/04/27 12:33:32 [792] <f+++++++++ texlive/Downloads/ChromeSetup.exe
2018/04/27 12:33:43 [792] <f+++++++++ texlive/Downloads/test.txt
2018/04/27 12:33:43 [792] <f+++++++++ texlive/Downloads/desktop.ini
```

Can you guys please help me and tell me where is my logic bad at?

Thank you in advance for all the answers.

EDIT_0:
At the end of this method I need to new log file look this:

```
2018/04/27 12:29:40 [792] Dir texlive/
2018/04/27 12:33:31 [792] CDir texlive/Downloads/
2018/04/27 12:33:31 [792] File texlive/Downloads/Backup.zip
2018/04/27 12:33:32 [792] File texlive/Downloads/ChromeSetup.exe
2018/04/27 12:33:43 [792] File texlive/Downloads/test.txt
2018/04/27 12:33:43 [792] File texlive/Downloads/desktop.ini
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function logEditor(strInputFile, strLogFileName)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, ForReading)
    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close

    'replaceOfStatus
    strNewText1 = Replace(strText, "cd+++++++++", "CDir")
    'this one is going to be ignored
    strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText1, "<f+++++++++", "FILE") 'USE THE MODIFIED strNewText1 STRING 

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLogFileName, ForWriting, True)
'   objFile.WriteLine strNewText1 'writed one YOU DONT NEED THIS LINE
    objFile.Write strNewText2 'ignored one HERE THE ENTIRE FILE IS BEING WRITTEN
    objFile.Close
End Function
```

Couple of changes

1. Since you want to do multiple replace - you need to make that happen cumulatively - like first replace CD++ and then use that modified string to replace
2. Once the replacements are made, just write the final string to the file

Comment: But i need to replace multiple status, because person reading the log has no idea about what CD***/F**/others means. In overall its something about 30 statuses i need to replace.

Comment: Now your question is bit different from the original question. As per the original you said that only the first status was changed and not others. I provided the algo tweak for that.